# On source change TextBox value is not binding to property in MVVM

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, mvvm

My ViewModel code to bind my Textbox is as followes

```
private float _maxKaxCalculate;
        public float MaxKaxCalculate
        {
            get { return _maxKaxCalculate; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _maxKaxCalculate)
                {
                    _maxKaxCalculate = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("MaxKaxCalculate");                    
                }
            }
        }
        public void CalculateMaxKaz()
        {            
            if (CouponList.Count > 0)
            {
                _maxKaxCalculate = 1;
                foreach (CouponDC cDC in CouponList)
                {
                    _maxKaxCalculate *= cDC.Rate;
                }
                _maxKaxCalculate *= Convert.ToSingle(TutarValue);
            }
            else
                _maxKaxCalculate = 0;

            _maxKaxCalculate = Convert.ToSingle(Math.Round(_maxKaxCalculate, 2));

        }

        private float _tutarValue;
        public float TutarValue
        {
            get { return _tutarValue; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _tutarValue)
                {
                    _tutarValue = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("TutarValue");
                }
            }
        }
```

My View section has the following code of the textbox

```
<TextBox Width="65" Text="{Binding Path=MaxKaxCalculate,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,StringFormat=N2}" Style="{StaticResource Input1}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,2,0,3"  />
```

My _maxKaxCalculate variable is getting some correct value but Textbox is not getting that value in View.Is UI refresh required or BeginInvoke required?please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set

```
_maxKaxCalculate = 0;
```

there will be no notification about the change. Use

```
MaxKaxCalculate = 0;
```

to use the setter of the property with notification.